# Calling a node script via PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, node.js

I am trying to make a website that allows you to create telegram bots (http://teleauth.host) and I need to execute a script that creates another script which should get executed via PM2. The script itself works, all the strings from the form get inserted into the database, its just the exec command, that won't work.

```
exec('/usr/bin/node /var/teleauth/scripts/write.js '.$file_name.' '.$shared_secret.' '.$http_api.' '.$admin_key.' && /usr/bin/pm2 start /var/teleauth/bots/'.$file_name.'.js');
```

This is the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Totally offtopic: Remove the background music from your page. Nobody likes that. | Ontopic: Do you get any errors? Whats happening?

Comment: You can try `exec('YourString 2>&1', $output); var_dump($output); //Redirects stderr to stdout, captures it in $output and prints it`

Comment: @Xatenev First of all, this is very common and popular in the area of ​​interest this page will be. Second, there are no errors, no nothing. It just acts like the exec part wouldn't be there.

Comment: @bytec0de You should also check the output of the command (see Xatenev's comment), not just PHP's warnings/errors. There could be file permissions problems, etc

Comment: @bytec0de You can also pass another variable into [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) after `$output` to see what the process return code is.

Comment: It prints `array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "sh: 1: fggfgf: not found" }` with `exec(''.$shared_secret.' 2>&1', $output); var_dump($output);`

Comment: Also, here's all of the code. https://hastebin.com/eluneniyin.xml

Comment: @bytec0de Why did you remove all the other code in your exec except $shared_secret? You want to call exactly the same exec() call you made before so you know whats going wrong.

Comment: Well, that gave me array(0) { }, I'm new to PHP and was confused.

Comment: That has nothing to do with PHP. Anyways try to execute the script you are trying to run via exec() manually in shell.

Comment: As you can see, it works. http://i.bytec0.de/5RH6C3y1.png

Comment: @bytec0de You ran it with the `root` user which is probably not the user your PHP is using.

Comment: PHP is using www-data and I can execute it with sudo without any problems. Still won't work with  PHP. http://i.bytec0.de/9cO940i6.png